# Using Target to Recognize a Cell Location

Tags: excel, range, cell, target, vba

I run into this issue a fair amount and am curious if someone can tell me why or how I can write this a little cleaner.

Below is my code and it does work.

```
If Target.Row = rTime.Offset(0, 1).Row Then
    If Target.Column = rTime.Offset(0, 1).Column Then
        cboStatus.Activate
    End If
End If
```

How come I can’t just write it like this?

```
If Target = rTime.Offset(0, 1) Then
    cboStatus.Activate
End If
```

If target is already a range then why do I need to specify the individual row and individual column? That second code will not work and I have tried many variations of it. I even tried something like `If Target.Range = range(“C4”) Then` or `If Target.Range = cells(4, 3) Then`, but neither of those worked either. I tried many variations of similar stuff. Although, I don’t want to use a specific range like `A4`, since I wanted to use the `rTime` like what is in the example, but I was just trying to figure this out.

Nothing seems to work, other than specifying the individual row and column each time. Can someone please explain this to me? Also, is there a better way to write this than what I did in the first example, which does work?

Thanks for anything that relieves my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default property of a range object is `.Value` so when you say `If Target = rTime.Offset(0, 1)`, it will always compare the values in that range rather than the address of those ranges.

One way is already shown by L42. Here is another way using `Intersect`

`If Not Intersect(Target, rtime.Offset(0, 1)) Is Nothing Then cboStatus.Activate`

**EDIT**

When you say `Target.Column` and `Target.Row`, you will always get the first column and the first row of the cell in that range, even if `Target` has multiple cells. To avoid this use the below to ensure that you have the desired `Target`. Your code will give you unexpected results even if there is a single cell in `Target`. For example, say the value of cell `B1` is equal to any other cell which at the moment is `target`. So if Cell `B1` = "Sid" and Cell `F1` = "Sid" and you select cell `F1` then you will get the "Hello World" message box.

For xl2003, you can use an additional check

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rtime As Range

    Set rtime = Range("A1")

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "you have chosen more than one cell"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, rtime.Offset(0, 1)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Hello World"
    End If
End Sub
```

For xl2007+, replace `Target.Cells.Count` with `Target.Cells.CountLarge`

**For L42**

Your method is correct but then you also will have to put the above check to get the correct results.

Comment: @ sid i've figured the comparison works only if objects holds single cell? if it is a range eg. `Range("A1:A2")` then it will not work since as you said, default property is `Value` and multiple values can't be compared all at the same time? is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think I will add one more thing to avoid confusion... One moment... updating the post.

Comment: Thank you both so much, not sure who to give the credit to, since you both were helpful. Since Sid put more information in, I will give the credit to him, but I did mark both of you up. This explains so much, and realized that I have been doing this wrong for a long time now. It looks like I have a few spreadsheets to go through and correct, even though they do work.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

**Edit1:** To cover Chis' concern

```
If Target.Address = rtime.Offset(0,1).Address(,,,True) then cboStatus.Activate
```

you cannot compare objects, just the properties? I'm not certain though.

Comment: + 1 Yup you need to get the `.Address`

Comment: You should really use `.Address(, , , TRUE)` just in case `rtime` is not on the same workbook and sheet as `Target`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Agree. Edited my answer for you :D although kinda late.